# Bandpass general equation to difference equation

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, transfer-function, bandpass

I know this is a very basic question and I am coming out from a quarter of DSP. I want to create a function in Java which can taken in two parameters, either `(double centerFrequency, double bandWidth)` or `(double startFrequency, double cutoffFrequency)`.

Based on the information I've gathered, I want a non-ideal IIR filter because this is for a project I am doing with an accelerometer that needs to be updated real-time. Hopefully I am not going too much into programming, but the general form of my filter function would be like this:

```
double BPFilter(double x, double centerFrequency, double bandWidth) {
    double filteredY;
    static double[] y = {0, 0, 0};
    //y[0] represents y[n]
    //y[1] represents y[n-1]
    //y[2] represents y[n-2]

    y[0] = A*y[2] + B*y[1] + C*x;
    y[2] = y[1];
    y[1] = y[0];
    return y[0];
}
```

What would be the best way to calculate `A`, `B`, and `C`? Currently I know how to do continuous transfer functions, $H(s)$, so if that is translatable to `A`, `B`, and `C` I could do it that way. The sampling rate is at $100\textrm{ Hz}$.

TL;DR: Discretize a continuous transfer function by hand (no MATLAB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transfer function of a continuous-time second-order band-pass filter is given by

$$H(s)=\frac{\frac{\omega_0}{Q}s}{s^2+\frac{\omega_0}{Q}s+\omega_0^2}\tag{1}$$

where $\omega_0$ is the center frequency in radians per second, and $Q$ is the [quality factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor). For $Q\gg 1$, the term $\omega_0/Q$ closely approximates the $3$ dB bandwidth $W$ (in radians per second). Note that the condition $Q\gg 1$ is equivalent to $W\ll\omega_0$.

If you want to transform the transfer function $(1)$ to the discrete-time domain, there are several possibilities. The two most commonly used ones are the [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform) and the [impulse invariance method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_invariance). Both of them are covered extensively in the literature and on the web (including this site). Note that the bilinear transform introduces frequency warping, so you have to pre-warp the parameters of the continuous-time filter in such a way that after the transformation the discrete-time filter has the desired properties. A very good explanation of IIR filter design using the bilinear transform can be found in chapter 11 of the (freely available) book [Introduction to Signal Processing](http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/intro2sp/) by S.J. Orfanidis.

You can find specific formulas for second-order discrete-time filters derived from the bilinear transform in the [Audio-EQ-Cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/). Also take a look at [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/109/4298) and its answers.

Comment: wow this is exactly what I was looking for! thank you for the help :)