# Discretizing a Controller with the Backward Difference Method

Tags: discrete-signals, control-systems, discretization

In the book "Modern Control Engineering" by Paraskevopoulos it's proved how to discretize a generic controller in the form:

$G(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{a}{s+a}$

where $a$ is a constant. Done this, the author says that it is possible to extend this procedure to a general case (without showing how), concluding that in order to discretize a controller $G(s)$ i have to simply substitute $s=\frac{1-z^{-1}}{T}$ where $T$ is the sampling period.

Since the author doesn't show how is possible to extend the procedure to a general controller. Can you explain to me ?

Comment: Related: [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/54033/4298).

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of hand-wavy, but you can look at this from two different perspectives:

One, you can look at $z^{-1}$ as a "back-step" operator; i.e. if $X(z) = \mathcal{Z}\lbrace x_n \rbrace$, then (with a few 'i's left undotted and 't's uncrossed) $\frac{X(z)}{z} = \mathcal{Z}\lbrace x_{n-1} \rbrace$.  You can also look at $s$ as a derivative operator: if $X(s) = \mathcal{Z}\lbrace x(t) \rbrace$, then $s X(s) = \mathcal{Z}\lbrace \frac{d}{dt}x(t) \rbrace$.

And -- the time derivative of $x(t)$ is approximately $\frac{d}{dt}x(t) \simeq \frac{x(t) - x(t - T)}{T}$.  If I throw caution to the wind and just sample the right side, that translates to, again roughly, $\frac{d}{dt}x(t) \simeq \frac{x_n - x_{n-1}}{T}$.  Now the Laplace of the left and the Z transform of the right gives $s X \simeq \frac{1 - z^{-1}}{T} X$.  Note that I have left off all pretense of a frequency domain variable on this -- I think that if there's an antithesis of "rigor" it must be "limpor", and we've just found it.

So you can take a system transfer function in $s$, expand it into a differential equation, then you can use the approximation $\frac{d}{dt}x(t) \simeq \frac{x(t) - x(t - T)}{T}$, then you can take the Z transform, then you turn the resulting difference equation into a transfer function in $z$ -- and you have just taken the very long way around to simply substituting $\frac{1 - z^{-1}}{T}$ for $s$.

The *other* way you can look at this is to observe that with a continuous-time system, the delay operator has a Laplace-domain transform: $\mathcal{L}\lbrace x(t - T)\rbrace = e^{-sT} X(s)$.  So you just *set $z^{-1} = e^{-sT}$*.  There's ways you can make this more rigorous, but compared to my above treatment this is already granite.

For $sT \ll 1$, $e^{-sT} \simeq 1 - sT$.  Substitute in $z^{-1} = e^{-sT}$ and solve for $s$ and you get $s \simeq \frac{1 - z^{-1}}{T}$.  Voila.  To get the first *forward* difference start with $z = e^{sT} \simeq 1 + sT$ and you find that $s \simeq \frac{z - 1}{T}$.  Use $z = e^{sT} = \frac{e^{\frac{sT}{2}}}{e^{-\frac{sT}{2}}}$ and you get [the Tustin approxmation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform).

Note, when you actually go to do these, the word *approximation*.  You can generally get by with control systems because you need to sample way faster than the plant dynamics anyway, but -- approximation.

Comment: Why the fact that the laplace transform of the derivative is $sX(s)$ and the zeta trasform of the discrete derivative is $\frac{1}{T}\frac{z-1}{z}X(z)$  tell us that, in order to discretize Laplace we have to substitute $s=\frac{1-z^{-1}}{T}$ ? Moreover, laplace and zeta trasform are different things to me ...
And why it holds for every $G(s)$ ? There could be also second and third derivatives...

Comment: It's an **approximation**.  Those properties of the Laplace transform and the z transform tell us that we can **approximate** differentiation by substituting $s = (1 - z^{-1})/T$.

Comment: If you treat the sampling process as a multiplication by a train of unit impulses, then the result is that the sampled-time signal equals $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \delta(t - nT) x(nT)$.  Take the Laplace transform of that and it equals the z transform with $z = e^{sT}$.  This should be in the first or second chapter of any signal processing book that deals with discrete-time signals.

Comment: I couldn't give you a super-rigorous mathematical proof of why It holds for every $G(s)$, but loosely speaking it holds because you can take $G(s)$ apart into a differential equation, then use the time-domain approximation for differentiation, then sample, then take the z transform.