# I often see here formula expressed in term of $z$. But what is $z$?

Tags: z-transform

While searching resources for generating pink noise (and with your help in the comments and answers of other questions), I came to such kind of formula:

> $$ H(z) = { .041 - .096z^{-1} + .051z^{-2} - .004z^{-3} \over{}  -2.495z^{-1} + 2.017z^{-2} - .522z^{-3}} $$
>
> (from https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/376/46389)

### What is $z$?

I know it should be obvious for anyone familiar with digital signal processing but for people coming from a different field, it is not obvious to know what this represents and how it relates to the signal amplitude or frequency or any other "tangible" parameter.

---

<sub>Edit: amusingly enough, the site suggested me the [z-tranform](/questions/tagged/z-tranform) tag for this question. I suspect I should consider that as a clue.</sub>

Comment: Please see this post as it goes into detail on what z is (z is any complex number): https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/how-why-are-the-mathcal-z-transform-and-unit-delays-related/31841#31841

Comment: Thanks for having pointed me to that great answer @Dan!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$z$ is interpreted as the time advance operator. $z^{-1}$ is the time delay operator.

So for a difference equation like
$$ y[n]=a x[n]+b x[n-1] $$
in the $z$ domain
$$ Y(z)=(a+ b z^{-1}) X(z)$$

Comment: Thanks, @Stanley. It's kind of a revelation. Does... that... mean... I can simply replace all $z^{-k}$ terms by $s[n-k]$ in the filter mentioned in the question above to have its expression in the time domain? Or do I need to plug some extra magic transformation somewhere?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux yeah, pretty much. See: the z-Transform :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much of this myself. Probably less than you. :) But I think something you're looking for is this:

https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html

It provides basic substitution functions (if I am understanding correctly) for converting between the time, z, and laplace domains.

Answer (score -1):

$z = e^{j\omega}$ is a convenient substitution for a complex valued function.

Comment: Thanks, @Samuel. I know complex numbers and I have (had?) some familiarities with Euler's complex notation. But starting from plain time-domain samples, how do I obtain that $z$? Or do I have just to consider my samples are the real part of that imaginary number? I doubt this would be so simple. Or it is?

Comment: Can someone please clarify why I got downvoted on this?  I answered the question "what is z" I don't see how this deserves a downvote.

Comment: Sylvain, I know it might be late, but starting with time domain samples, as we can see $z = e^{j\omega} = cos(\omega t) + jsin(\omega t)$... so in short you can convert your time domain samples to a complex number "z" by choosing some $\omega$ and using the relationship I described.