# What does z^(-1) represent here?

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, z-transform, laplace-transform

I understand that when you have a Laplace function, you can do a bilinear or forward/backward Euler substitution for $s$ to phrase it in terms of $z^{-1}$. In a typical filter, $z^{-1}$ represents the input to the filter delayed by one sample.

But what about if it's something that's not really meant to be a filter? Ie. Something that's not really meant to get an input?

eg. Let's say you have the equation, which comes from work using the differentiation theory for Laplace transforms:

[image]

Where V=velocity, m=mass, v0= initial velocity, and R=impedance.

This can be phrased in terms of time as:

[image]

I understand how to use the time based version. You can simply run a timer from time 0 and add the sampling period to it each sample, and put that timer in for "t" to get the output each sample.

But what about the Laplace version? If you tried to sub in say a backward Euler $s=(1−z^{−1})/T$, what does $z^{-1}$ represent?

$V(z) = (m * v0) / (m * [(1−z^{−1})/T] + (2 * R))$

What now is $z^{-1}$? From a coding standpoint, what do I put into this equation for $z^{-1}$? ie. What do you delay by one sample and put back into the equation here?

ie. If you were writing this equation in C++, what would you write for the $z^{-1}$?
Thanks.

**Edit: I appreciate the answers but I think they're missing what I'm looking for so please let me rephrase:**

I can code the simple time based equation like this:

```
velocity = v0 * exp ((-2 * R * timer)/mass);
timer = timer + (1/sampleRate);
```

And it will output velocity appropriately at each sample.

I am asking, how would I write some basic code to do the same with the z equation? I cannot understand what variable or data to put in for $z^{-1}$.

```
s = (1-z_1)/T;
velocity = (m * v0) / ((m * s) + (2*R));
```

Now in this code, **what exactly is z_1?**

Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to answer this at this link- does this help you? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/how-why-are-the-mathcal-z-transform-and-unit-delays-related/31841#31841

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'm sure if I understood all that I wouldn't have this question, but that's a bit over my head, and my question is quite specific. I'm specifically wondering, in an equation like that, if I'm coding it in C++, WHAT EXACTLY do I put in for $z^{-1}$? $z^{-1}$ is a sample delay. But what do I delay by one sample and put in the equation to get an appropriate output?

Comment: @DanBoschen I added a bit of C++ code to clarify my question exactly. Can you perhaps help? This is driving me crazy. Thanks again. I am learning for whatever it's worth.

Comment: I get it-- I think Matt answered it clearly, take a closer look at his answer.  v[n] is your current result and v[n-1] would be the result you last had before you iterated. Does that makes sense now?

Comment: In that case is it: z_1 = velocity; s = (1-z_1)/T; velocity = (m * v0) / ((m * s) + (2*R)); That looks messy in one line, but the idea is I am just using the already established velocity from the prior sample for z_1, then recalculating it from this. I thought I tried that and it didn't work. If that's right I'll go try it again.

Comment: No it is not a simple substitution las you are doing, $z^{-1}$ is not velocity but the tranform of a unit delay -- instead implement Matt's equation (2) exactly as he shows.

Comment: Okay. So you can't use the z-based equation directly. You need to process it further to get a directly usable equation. I did not understand that. How did he get from equation 1 to equation 2? Thanks again.

Comment: That's the inverse z-tranform, but it may be easier for you to see how to go from equation (2) to (1)  which is the z-transform: the z transform of $v[n]$ is $V(z)$ and the z transform of $v[n-1]$ is $V(z)z^{-1}$ So replace v[n] and v[n-1] with V(z) and $V(z)z^{-1}$ and you should be able to rearrange your way back to equation (1). But I think Matt answered your question as written, didn't he?

Comment: I see. That's helpful. Yes I am understanding now. I will have to test this "inverse z-tranform" procedure out on a few other equations to be sure I can do it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\mathcal{Z}$-transform expression corresponds to a difference equation which can be solved for $v[n]$, the velocity at sample $n$. From

$$V(z)=\frac{v_0T}{1+\frac{2RT}{m}-z^{-1}}\tag{1}$$

you get

$$v[n]=\frac{1}{1+\frac{2RT}{m}}\big(v[n-1]+v_0T\big)\tag{2}$$

So the delay operates on the samples $v[n]$. You just choose an initial condition (e.g., $v[-1]=0$), and you can solve the difference equation $(2)$ for $v[n]$, $n\ge 0$.

EDIT: In reaction to your edited question, I would like to ask you to think about the Laplace transform $V(s)$. What would you put in for $s$? The answer is "nothing", it's just an equation that can be solved for the desired transform $V(s)$, which can then be transformed back to the time domain. Of course, you can replace $s$ by $j\omega$ (in case the imaginary axis is inside the region of convergence), and analyze the frequency behavior of the function. The same is true for the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform: set $z=e^{j\omega}$ to obtain the frequency response. But often you just use the Laplace transform and the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform in order to solve differential (difference) equations.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I understand better now. So I can't use equation 1 directly to get my velocity. I need to process it into equation 2 which I can then use. Can you clarify how you got from equation 1 to equation 2?

Comment: @mike: It's just like the equation for $V(s)$, you can't directly use it to compute $v(t)$; you need to transform it back to the time domain. As for obtaining the difference equation $(2)$, just multiply both sides of $(1)$ by the denominator on the RHS and note that multiplication with $z^{-1}$ corresponds to a delay of one sample in the time domain.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I understand and reproduced your derivation. So you basically need to get rid of your $z^{-1}$ terms and have something in terms of [n-1] as you showed to get something you can use. Okay. Thanks

Comment: @mike: that's right.