Fourier transform - connection between delaying $k$ steps as $e^{-jkω}$ and magnitude of the frequency $\omega$
Trying to understand what Fourier transform does. In my understanding, if there is a discrete signal $f_k$ where $k$ is an integer sample index ranging from $-\infty < k < \infty$, Fourier transform gives the magnitude $A(\omega)$ at the frequency $\omega$ as
$$ F(\omega) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} f_k e^{-jk \omega} \ .$$
The Fourier operation of taking a product with $e^{-jk\omega}$ seems to me delaying the signal's $\omega$ frequency component by $k$ sample steps. The question is why delaying $k$ steps (and summing over all $k$) can give the magnitude $A(\omega)$ for each frequency $\omega$?
Also $e^{-jk\omega}$ is a negative rotation operation on a unit circle. I am baffled why rotation or delay can lead to magnitude. What are the connections between them?

Intuition with mathematical operations is always a bit tricky and depends a lot on what you personally perceive to be "intuitive". That depends a lot on your personal background: Are you already comfortable with Laplace Transform and the various flavors of the Fourier Transform?

Z transform is the discrete version of the Laplace Transform. The transformation you are referencing in your question is a special case of the Z transform, that is called the Discrete Fourier Transform, where the modulus of $z=r e^{j\omega}$ is 1

Does this answer help you?: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/how-why-are-the-mathcal-z-transform-and-unit-delays-related/31841#31841

@Hilmar, thanks for the follow up. I am not yet confident in Laplace but went through Fourier Series, Fourier Transform and DFT so far, and came to Z-transform.

The OP's equation is not the z-transform.
The z transform is given as:
$$F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x[n] z^{-n}$$
And from that we see that the z-transform of a unit delay is $z^{-1}$.
If we evaluate the resulting z-transform on the unit circle, specifically setting $z=e^{j\omega}$ for a continuous frequency $\omega \in [0, 2\pi)$ in normalized radian units of radians/sample, we will get the frequency response $H(e^{j\omega})$ for the system with transfer function $H(z)$.  This response will extend from DC ($\omega=0$) to the sampling rate ($\omega = 2\pi$).
This would appear as follows, which is the Frequency Response:
$$F(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x[n] e^{-j\omega n}$$
As an intuitive example as to how this leads to the magnitude (and phase) of the frequency response, consider the simple network of a sample added to the previous sample as a two sample moving average (as with any moving average we would expect it to be a low-pass filter):
$$y[n] = (x[n] + x[n-1])/2$$
The z transform of this would be:
$$Y(z) = (X(z) + X(z)z^{-1})/2$$
Leading to the transfer function:
$$H(z) = Y(z)/X(z) = 0.5 + 0.5 z^{-1}$$
The frequency response is then:
$$H(e^{j\omega}) = 0.5 + 0.5 e^{-j\omega}$$
The term $e^{-j\omega}$ is itself not a delay but a value that has a constant magnitude of one and a phase that is directly proportional to frequency (conveniently the same value in this case). When $\omega=0$ or DC we get $0.5 + 0.5 = 1$. When $\omega = \pi$ (which is Nyquist or half the sampling rate), we would get the result $1-1=0$ or full cancellation. Thus we have a low pass filter.
This is no different from a delay in a continuous time system (such as a lossless cable) where the Fourier Transform of a delay given by $x(t-\tau) \leftrightarrow e^{-j\tau f} X(f)$

Consider with the cable if we put in a very low frequency tone, the phase between the input and output of that cable would be very small, but as we increase the frequency, with a fixed time delay given by $\tau$ the phase between the input and output will increase proportionally. There will be a frequency where the phase is exactly $2\pi$, so if we were to split our signal and add the output of the cable to a copy of the input without any delay (which is the digital system we described above), we would get complete cancellation. For our digital system given as $H(z) = 0.5 + 0.5z^{-1}$, this is exactly what would occur at $f_s/2$!

For further intuition on understanding the z-transform, see the answer to DSP.SE 31830.

When you are delaying by $-k\omega$ for all $k$ over the length of the signal, you are essentially "tracking" the frequency $\omega$ in the signal. Because the DFT is an orthobasis, other frequencies will tend to cancel out, whereas the signal at frequency $\omega$ will tend to add in phase and produce a big magnitude. So, from this perspective, you're basically aligning the phase of the signal so that it coherently adds with a complex exponential at frequency $\omega$ to produce a magnitude. (Tried to put this in layman's terms as Dan did a good job with the math side of this perspective).
While you can view the Fourier transform from this perspective, I personally don't find it to be the most intuitive. As I explained in this answer, the Fourier transform is an orthobasis expansion. That is to say, we decompose a signal into a set of discrete "building blocks", in this case frequency components. While I would personally maintain this is the most complete and versatile understanding of the Fourier transform, if you are not brushed up on your linear algebra skills, this can be a difficult concept to grasp.
Another way to view the Fourier transform in commonly known signal processing terms is as a matched filterbank, as I explain in this answer. The matched filter is the optimal linear filter for maximizing the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) in additive noise. So, the Fourier transform is essentially a linear filterbank that optimizes the SNR at each complex frequency $e^{j\omega}$ assuming that only additive noise is present. The delay in this case comes directly from the convolution, which is a delay-and-sum operation.
Since you mentioned stuff about the Laplace/Z-transform, I'll give a brief discussion here. The Z-transform (in the causal case) is defined as
\begin{equation}
F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n}
\end{equation}
where $z$ is some complex number. Since complex numbers can be represented as magnitude and phase, we can say
\begin{align}
F(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x[n]\left(Ae^{j\omega}\right)^{-n} \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x[n]A^{-n}e^{-j\omega n}
\end{align}
Therefore, it represents both decay and rotation (oscillation), and is a generalization of the DFT. If we assume $A=1$, we get the DFT.
